# CORS error in PouchDB with CORS enabled in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have CORS enabled in CouchDB:
[image]

[image]

I run the app on Windows 8.1, serving it with hapi.js.

When viewing it in Chrome after a while this error message appears in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError {status: 500, name: "unknown_error", message: "Database encountered an unknown error", error: true, toString: function}
```

Firefox aborts accessing CouchDB, for instance:
http://127.0.0.1:5984/user_z_at_z_p_ch/?_nonce=1431328831527,
then reports that a cross origin request was blocked.

I have tried to run add-cors-to-couchdb but I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\alex> add-cors-to-couchdb
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that I missed one header in the cors section of config.ini in couchdb: `x-csrf-token`

cors now works with these headers:

```
accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token
```

I have no idea why this happens but hey: it works

Comment: The reason is that the browser rejects to execute a request that is initiated by the JS-code when at least one header of the request is not in the CORS config. You can debug in your browser the former HEAD request that the browser do before. Every header mentioned have to be in the CORS config. Its like a quick question before: "Dear server! Would you allow me to send such a request?" If the answer is "No!" the browser will not request - you get the error message immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your CORS settings look correct. Are you sure your CouchDB is externally accessible from the hostname/port you're using?

If `add-cors-to-couchdb` is failing, it's because the default CouchDB at `localhost:5984` is inaccessible. It has options to specify a CouchDB at another URL.

Comment: That is weird because futon works perfectly on http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html, and also fauxton. Also: curl http://localhost:5984/ returns status 200

Comment: Hm, well if curl is working, then you can use the alternative curl approach: https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb#what-it-does

Comment: well, curl on windows... I gave up doing anything more complicated than the basic command

Comment: I tried running add-cors-to-couchdb on ubuntu 14.04 following the "ubuntu special instructions" but got an error: [Error: got a 401 code]

Comment: 401 means you are unauthorized, so you need to put in an admin username/password. :)

Comment: oh, yes, now add-cors-to-couchdb works an windows and on ubuntu