# CORS requests with preflight on CouchDB

Tags: rest, cors, couchdb, http-status-code-405, preflight

We are trying to send HTTP cross domain requests to CouchDB.

To achieve this, we set up CouchDB with the following settings (inspired from the [add-cors-to-couchdb tool](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb/blob/master/index.js#L7-L26)):

```
[HTTPD]
enable_cors = true

[CORS]
origins = *
credentials = true
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token
```

And wrote code similar to this (but not hardcoded of course):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch("http://acme.org:5984/mydb/323958d9b42be0aaf811a3c96b4e5d9c", {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {'If-Match': "1-0c2099c9793c2f4bf3c9fd6751e34f95"}
      }).then(x => {
        if (x.ok) return x.json().then(console.log);
        console.error(x.statusText);
      });
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

While it works fine with `GET` and `POST`, we get `405 Method not allowed` on `DELETE`. The browser tells that the preflight response (to the `OPTIONS` request) was not successful, while the server indicates `{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only DELETE,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,COPY allowed"}`.

We tried both with CouchDB 2.1.1 and 1.6.1. We also tried to replace `origins: *` with `origins: http://localhost:8080` (where 8080 is the port serving the HTML above). We tried also to set `credentials` to `false`.

Comment: Please don't use `origin: *` as it allows CSRF exploits!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [a comment by @Ingo Radatz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161843/cors-error-in-pouchdb-with-cors-enabled-in-couchdb#comments-30210932) to a related question, I finally got that **EVERY** header used in the request must be included in CouchDB CORS settings.

In my personal case, I had to include `if-match` in the accepted headers:

```
[HTTPD]
enable_cors = true

[CORS]
origins = *
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, if-match
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this tip @Aurélien, I've finally figured out how to configure my vue app using couchdb.

Comment: @IanWootten, I'm pleased to help :)