# CouchDB, EventSource and OPTIONS method (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: couchdb, server-sent-events

I would like to implement [Event Source](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/changes.html?highlight=eventsource#event-source) feed of `_changes` for some documents in publicly readable database in CouchDB. Unfortunately, I get 405 error and:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://COUCHDOMAIN:6984/DBNAME/_changes?feed=eventsource&filter=_doc_ids&doc_ids=[%22DOCID%22]&since=now&include_docs=true&heartbeat=44000' from origin 'https://CLIENTDOMAIN' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I do not understand why I get `Allow: GET,POST,HEAD` in response while in CORS config, there is also `OPTIONS`... `EventSource` constructed with `withCredentials: true/false`, no difference...

I will appreciate any suggestion.

My CORS configuration:

```
[cors]
origins = https://CLIENTDOMAIN
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS
credentials = true
```

Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /DBNAME/_changes?feed=eventsource&filter=_doc_ids&doc_ids=[%22DOCID%22]&since=now&include_docs=true&heartbeat=44000 HTTP/1.1
Host: COUCHDOMAIN:6984
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control
Origin: https://CLIENTDOMAIN
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; LM-V405) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://CLIENTDOMAIN/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,pl-PL;q=0.8,pl;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://CLIENTDOMAIN
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Allow: GET,POST,HEAD
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 69
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2022 20:04:06 GMT
Server: CouchDB/3.2.1 (Erlang OTP/20)
X-Couch-Request-ID: ab68310597
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
```

General (from chrome dev tools):

```
Request URL: https://COUCHDOMAIN:6984/DBNAME/_changes?feed=eventsource&filter=_doc_ids&doc_ids=[%22DOCID%22]&since=now&include_docs=true&heartbeat=44000
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: COUCHIP:6984
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914749/2626200):

```
[cors]
origins = https://CLIENTDOMAIN
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, cache-control
...
```

Comment: Does this cause an OPTIONS to respond with a 2XX success?  If so the CouchDB documentation needs to be express it.  Of course I may have overlooked this, but I have yet to find it in the docs.

Comment: Yes, it gives 204.